# Arrange a list of Pairs

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list of pairs(combinations from 1 to n) and I am trying to arrange them in different lists so that a all the pairs of the list have different elements.

Example

Input:

```
[(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 6),(2, 3),(2, 4),(2, 5),
 (2, 6),(3, 4),(3, 5),(3, 6),(4, 5),(4, 6),(5, 6)]
```

Output:

> l1 :[(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6)]
>
> l2 :[(1, 3) (2, 5) (4, 6)]
>
> l3 :[(1, 4) (2, 6) (3, 5)]
>
> l4 :[(1, 5) (3, 6) (2, 4)]
>
> l5 :[(1, 6) (4, 5) (2, 3)]

```
public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> roundTeams(ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> allPairs) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> roundTeams = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>>();
    int counter = 0;
    while (!allPairs.isEmpty()) {

        ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> c_round = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();

        while (c_round.size() < 3) { // 3 is the length of the output 
                         //list so when using the long list here will be 10
            for (Iterator<Pair<String, String>> iterator = allPairs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Pair<String, String> c = iterator.next();
                if (isValidPair(c, c_round)) {
                    c_round.add(c);
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            if (c_round.size() < 3) {    // same here 
                Pair<String, String> a = c_round.get(c_round.size() - 1);
                c_round.remove(a);
                allPairs.remove(a);
                allPairs.add(a);
            }

        }
        roundTeams.put(counter, c_round);
        counter++;

    }
    return roundTeams;

}

public static boolean isValidPair(Pair<String, String> pair, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> pairs) {

    if (pairs.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    for (Pair<String, String> c_pair : pairs) {
        if (c_pair.getKey().equals(pair.getKey()) || c_pair.getValue().equals(pair.getValue())
                || c_pair.getKey().equals(pair.getValue()) || c_pair.getValue().equals(pair.getKey())) {
            return false;

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have done it but it works only when I'm using a small input like the one above.
If I put a larger input like the one below one it goes on an infinite loop.

> (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7) (1, 8) (1, 9) (1, 10) (1,
>   11) (1, 12) (1, 13) (1, 14) (1, 15) (1, 16) (1, 17) (1, 18) (1, 19)
>   (1, 20) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6) (2, 7) (2, 8) (2, 9) (2, 10) (2,
>   11) (2, 12) (2, 13) (2, 14) (2, 15) (2, 16) (2, 17) (2, 18) (2, 19)
>   (2, 20) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6) (3, 7) (3, 8) (3, 9) (3, 10) (3, 11) (3,
>   12) (3, 13) (3, 14) (3, 15) (3, 16) (3, 17) (3, 18) (3, 19) (3, 20)
>   (4, 5) (4, 6) (4, 7) (4, 8) (4, 9) (4, 10) (4, 11) (4, 12) (4, 13) (4,
>   14) (4, 15) (4, 16) (4, 17) (4, 18) (4, 19) (4, 20) (5, 6) (5, 7) (5,
>   8) (5, 9) (5, 10) (5, 11) (5, 12) (5, 13) (5, 14) (5, 15) (5, 16) (5,
>   17) (5, 18) (5, 19) (5, 20) (6, 7) (6, 8) (6, 9) (6, 10) (6, 11) (6,
>   12) (6, 13) (6, 14) (6, 15) (6, 16) (6, 17) (6, 18) (6, 19) (6, 20)
>   (7, 8) (7, 9) (7, 10) (7, 11) (7, 12) (7, 13) (7, 14) (7, 15) (7, 16)
>   (7, 17) (7, 18) (7, 19) (7, 20) (8, 9) (8, 10) (8, 11) (8, 12) (8, 13)
>   (8, 14) (8, 15) (8, 16) (8, 17) (8, 18) (8, 19) (8, 20) (9, 10) (9,
>   11) (9, 12) (9, 13) (9, 14) (9, 15) (9, 16) (9, 17) (9, 18) (9, 19)
>   (9, 20) (10, 11) (10, 12) (10, 13) (10, 14) (10, 15) (10, 16) (10, 17)
>   (10, 18) (10, 19) (10, 20) (11, 12) (11, 13) (11, 14) (11, 15) (11,
>   16) (11, 17) (11, 18) (11, 19) (11, 20) (12, 13) (12, 14) (12, 15)
>   (12, 16) (12, 17) (12, 18) (12, 19) (12, 20) (13, 14) (13, 15) (13,
>   16) (13, 17) (13, 18) (13, 19) (13, 20) (14, 15) (14, 16) (14, 17)
>   (14, 18) (14, 19) (14, 20) (15, 16) (15, 17) (15, 18) (15, 19) (15,
>   20) (16, 17) (16, 18) (16, 19) (16, 20) (17, 18) (17, 19) (17, 20)
>   (18, 19) (18, 20) (19, 20)

My code is quite messy and it's probably gonna be hard to figure out what's wrong so could you tell me any other way to solve this? 
Thank you.

Comment: I recommend stepping through this with a debugger to see what's really happening.  Also, are you sure it's an infinite loop, not just a very long one?

Comment: you're using recursion so it doesn't take much to get into a situation where it takes a long time to execute or to throw an out of memory error

Comment: Why do you remove the last thing from the list, in the block that starts `if (c_round.size() < 3) {`?  Surely that will just make everything take longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another different approach.  Trying to optimize this problem with a try-test algorithm increases the computational load exponentially.  Solutions up to 12 teams are easy but then the program starts to bog down.  There is a direct way to get the answer with O(n) complexity.

Consider that there is a fixed set of teams and each team appears once per round, all the rows are some permutation of the others.  The pattern for that permutation is not too difficult to find.  Consider this pattern to find round 3:

```
Round 1 before:                   [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10)]
Round 1 after transform:          [(1,2), (4,3), (6,5), (8,7), (10,9)]
Round 1 after swap (new round 3): [(1,4), (2,6), (3,8), (5,10), (7,9)]
```

Starting with the first round, round 2 is just a "swap" of the left/right elements on adjacent pairs. Round 3 is based on round 1 and is a "transform" or exchange of left/right elements for all pairs except the first, followed by a swap.  The output for twenty teams is:

```
1: [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12), (13,14), (15,16), (17,18), (19,20)]
2: [(1,3), (2,5), (4,7), (6,9), (8,11), (10,13), (12,15), (14,17), (16,19), (18,20)]
3: [(1,4), (2,6), (3,8), (5,10), (7,12), (9,14), (11,16), (13,18), (15,20), (17,19)]
4: [(1,5), (3,7), (2,9), (4,11), (6,13), (8,15), (10,17), (12,19), (14,20), (16,18)]
5: [(1,6), (4,8), (2,10), (3,12), (5,14), (7,16), (9,18), (11,20), (13,19), (15,17)]
6: [(1,7), (5,9), (3,11), (2,13), (4,15), (6,17), (8,19), (10,20), (12,18), (14,16)]
7: [(1,8), (6,10), (4,12), (2,14), (3,16), (5,18), (7,20), (9,19), (11,17), (13,15)]
8: [(1,9), (7,11), (5,13), (3,15), (2,17), (4,19), (6,20), (8,18), (10,16), (12,14)]
9: [(1,10), (8,12), (6,14), (4,16), (2,18), (3,20), (5,19), (7,17), (9,15), (11,13)]
10: [(1,11), (9,13), (7,15), (5,17), (3,19), (2,20), (4,18), (6,16), (8,14), (10,12)]
11: [(1,12), (10,14), (8,16), (6,18), (4,20), (2,19), (3,17), (5,15), (7,13), (9,11)]
12: [(1,13), (11,15), (9,17), (7,19), (5,20), (3,18), (2,16), (4,14), (6,12), (8,10)]
13: [(1,14), (12,16), (10,18), (8,20), (6,19), (4,17), (2,15), (3,13), (5,11), (7,9)]
14: [(1,15), (13,17), (11,19), (9,20), (7,18), (5,16), (3,14), (2,12), (4,10), (6,8)]
15: [(1,16), (14,18), (12,20), (10,19), (8,17), (6,15), (4,13), (2,11), (3,9), (5,7)]
16: [(1,17), (15,19), (13,20), (11,18), (9,16), (7,14), (5,12), (3,10), (2,8), (4,6)]
17: [(1,18), (16,20), (14,19), (12,17), (10,15), (8,13), (6,11), (4,9), (2,7), (3,5)]
18: [(1,19), (17,20), (15,18), (13,16), (11,14), (9,12), (7,10), (5,8), (3,6), (2,4)]
19: [(1,20), (18,19), (16,17), (14,15), (12,13), (10,11), (8,9), (6,7), (4,5), (2,3)]
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

public class roundTeams {

    public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> buildRounds(int numberOfTeams) {

        if (numberOfTeams % 2 != 0  ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("An even number of teams is required");
        }

        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> roundTeams = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>>();

        // Build first round
        ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> round = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
        for (int i=1; i<=numberOfTeams; ) {
            Pair<String, String> pair = Pair.of(""+i++, ""+i++);
            round.add(pair);
        }
        roundTeams.put(0,round);

        // Build other rounds
        int numberOfRounds = (numberOfTeams - 1);
        for (int i=1; i<numberOfRounds; i++) {
            roundTeams.put(i, transformRound(roundTeams, i));
        }

        return roundTeams;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new round based on existing rounds.
     * @param roundTeams  an array list of rounds. It must have at least one "seed" round.
     * @param i  The zero-based index of the round to add.
     * @return the new round.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> transformRound(
            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> roundTeams,
            int i) {

        if (roundTeams.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("roundTeams is empty. It must have at least one seed round.");

        ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> round = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();

        if (i>1) {
            // Clone is important here as we will be changing the round values to
            // create a new round and don't want to change the old values.
            round = (ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>) roundTeams.get(i-2).clone(); 

            // Transform/rotate the elements in pairs 2 on
            for (int j=1; j < round.size(); j++) {
                Pair<String, String> pair = round.get(j);
                String key = pair.getKey();
                String value = pair.getValue();
                pair = Pair.of(value, key);
                round.set(j, pair);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Since there is no "zero" round, the second round is based on the 
            // first/seed round without the transform.
            round = (ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>) roundTeams.get(0).clone();
        }

        // Swap right-left elements in neighboring pairs
        for (int j=1; j < round.size(); j++) {
            Pair<String, String> pair = round.get(j-1);
            String key1 = pair.getKey();
            String value1 = pair.getValue();
            pair = round.get(j);
            String key2 = pair.getKey();
            String value2 = pair.getValue();
            pair = Pair.of(key1, key2);
            round.set(j-1, pair);
            pair = Pair.of(value1, value2);
            round.set(j, pair);
        }
        return round;
    }

    final static int NUM_TEAMS = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> rounds = buildRounds(NUM_TEAMS);

        for (int i = 0; i < rounds.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + ": " + rounds.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You run into a problem with in the `while (c_round.size() < n)` loop.  The problem with this condition is that it will loop infinitely when c_round.size() < n which can occur in a few cases.  Consider rounds of size 3 when you only have five teams.  Each round could only have a possible two matches.

If the number of teams is higher, you can run into the similar situation when the final round has too few matches left to create a full round.

To solve the problem, you have to flag that situation and break out of the loop.

Here is a sample below.  The output for 9 teams and round size of 4 is

```
Number of teams: 9
Max Round Size: 4
Possible Combinations (36 total)
(1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) 
(2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9) 
(3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9) 
(4,5) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (4,9) 
(5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9) 
(6,7) (6,8) (6,9) 
(7,8) (7,9) 
(8,9) 

Rounds
0: (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) (7,8) 
1: (1,3) (2,4) (5,7) (6,8) 
2: (1,4) (2,3) (5,8) (6,7) 
3: (1,5) (2,6) (3,7) (4,8) 
4: (1,6) (2,5) (3,8) (4,7) 
5: (1,7) (2,8) (3,5) (4,6) 
6: (1,8) (2,7) (3,6) (4,5) 
7: (1,9) 
8: (2,9) 
9: (3,9) 
10: (4,9) 
11: (5,9) 
12: (6,9) 
13: (7,9) 
14: (8,9)
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

public class roundTeams {

    public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> roundTeams(ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> allPairs) {

        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> roundTeams = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>>();
        int counter = 0;

        while (!allPairs.isEmpty()) {

            ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> c_round = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();

            boolean fullRound = false;
            while (!fullRound) { 
                for (Iterator<Pair<String, String>> iterator = allPairs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    Pair<String, String> c = iterator.next();
                    if (isValidPair(c, c_round)) {
                        c_round.add(c);
                        iterator.remove();
                        if (c_round.size() == MAX_ROUND_SIZE) {
                            fullRound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // There are no other matches. We're done. 
                fullRound = true;
            }
            roundTeams.put(counter, c_round);
            counter++;
        }
        return roundTeams;
    }

    public static boolean isValidPair(Pair<String, String> pair, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> pairs) {

        if (pairs.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Pair<String, String> c_pair : pairs) {
            if (c_pair.getKey().equals(pair.getKey()) || c_pair.getValue().equals(pair.getValue())
                    || c_pair.getKey().equals(pair.getValue()) || c_pair.getValue().equals(pair.getKey())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    final static int MAX_ROUND_SIZE = 4;
    final static int NUM_TEAMS = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> allPairs = new ArrayList();
        Pair<String, String> pair;

        System.out.printf("Number of teams: %s\nMax Round Size: %s\n", NUM_TEAMS, MAX_ROUND_SIZE);
        System.out.printf("Possible Combinations (%S total)\n", NUM_TEAMS*(NUM_TEAMS-1)/2  );
        for (int i=1; i < NUM_TEAMS; i++) { // First index never reaches the number Teams
            for (int j=i+1; j <= NUM_TEAMS; j++) {
                pair = Pair.of(""+i, ""+j);
                allPairs.add(pair);
                System.out.print(pair + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\nRounds\n");

        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>> rounds = roundTeams(allPairs);

        for (int i = 0; i < rounds.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(i + ": ");
            for (Pair<String,String> match : rounds.get(i)) {
                System.out.print(match + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output lists need to have the same size and there is only one way to arrange all the pairs so you can get the correct output (19 lists each with 10 pairs).